# Getting error "left of '.toString' must have class/struct/union", even though there should be a fitting object left of toString

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have to programm some aspects of the game Skat for class. Knowing the game/the game's rules isn't important for task though. (I don't know it either.)

I haven't finished the programm and just wanted to run a simple test, but am already getting an error, that I can't seem to fix. Basically I create a new object of the class "SkatGame" called "one", and then I want to output all cards in the "deck" of "one" to the console. However that doesn't work and the error seems to indicate that "one" is no object of a class, i don't know why though.

I copied my whole code, but highlighted the important parts i though to be important (for lack of knowledge of a better tool) via the comments at the side. Any help would be appreciated.

main.cpp-File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector> 
#include "Header.h"

int main() {
    SkatGame one();
    one.toString();  //error in this line

}
```

Header.h-File

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <array>


enum Suit { KARO = 0, HERZ, PIK, KREUZ };                                           
enum Face { SIEBEN = 0, ACHT, NEUN, ZEHN, BUBE, DAME, KOENIG, ASS };
int const skatSize = 2;
int const deckSize = 32;
int const playerSize = 10;

class Card {                                                    
public:
    Card();
    Card(Suit, Face);
    Suit getSuit();
    Face getFace();
    std::string toString();
private:
    Suit suit;
    Face face;
};


class SkatGame {
public:
    SkatGame();                             //!important line
    void shuffle();
    void deal();
    std::string toString();
    std::array <Card, skatSize> getSkat();                  
private:
    std::array <Card, deckSize> deck;
    std::array <Card, playerSize> player1;
    std::array <Card, playerSize> player2;
    std::array <Card, playerSize> player3;
    std::array <Card, skatSize> skat;
};
```

detailed class-definitions file (.cpp)

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
//#include <stdlib.h>


Card::Card() {};                                                    
Card::Card(Suit gesinnung, Face Zahl)
    : suit(gesinnung), face(Zahl)
{};
Suit Card::getSuit() {                                              
    return Card::suit;
}
Face Card::getFace() {
    return Card::face;
}
std::string Card::toString() {                                 //!important part begin
    std::string zurueck;
    zurueck = std::to_string(Card::suit) + " " + std::to_string(Card::face);
    return zurueck;
}                             //!important part end



SkatGame::SkatGame()
{
int a, b, e = 0;

for (a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b <= 7; b++) {
            SkatGame::deck[e] = Card(static_cast<Suit>(a), static_cast<Face>(b));
            e++;
    }
}
}
void SkatGame::shuffle() {
    int a, card1, card2;
    Card hold;
    for (a = 0; a < 1000; a++){
        card1 = rand() %32;
        card2 = rand() %32;
        hold = SkatGame::deck[card1];
        SkatGame::deck[card1] = SkatGame::deck[card2];
        SkatGame::deck[card2] = hold;
    }
}
std::string SkatGame::toString() {                      //!important part begin
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
        std::cout << (SkatGame::deck[i]).toString() << std::endl;
    };
    return "justatest";
}                                                          //!important part end
```

EDIT: Removing the brackets behind one during the declaration worked.
So "SkatGame one;" instead of "SkatGame one();".

Comment: Did you, at least, try to search for the error you are getting? This is pretty commonly asked question..

Comment: Yeah apparently too superficial (I read something about pointers in a similar question, and that didn't seem to fit my problem or I didn't understand it correctly.)

Answer (score -2):

You are declaring a function 'one' that takes no arguments and returns a 'SkatGame'. To call it you write 'one() ;'

Comment: "To call it you write 'one() ;'" It can't be called, and even if it could why would that be relevant?

Comment: It's relevant to answering the question, why doesn't it compile. With the code in question it will compile, but won't link (undefined reference to `one()'). This might demonstrate it better: #include<iosgtream> struct SkatGame{}; int main(){ SkatGame one(); one(); } SkatGame one(){ std::cout << "This is the one\n";}